# sql converting int to datetime, overflow issues Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type varchar

Tags: sql-server, datetime, int

I have a value of `20070807000000` i tried CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),20070807000000))
but i'm getting the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type varchar.`

What can i do in order to get this to a datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
select 
    CONVERT (datetime, convert(char(8), left(ltrim(20070807000000), 8)))
```

Result:2007-08-07 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(20070807000000 as varchar(20)),1,8) as datetime)
```

Result: `August, 07 2007 00:00:00+0000`

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21000/0)

Comment: Oh noes! [VARCHAR without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)?

Comment: Also why not just `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),` then you don't have to mess with substring...

Answer (score 0):

An extra answer. You can provide a datetime format to your output:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST( SUBSTRING(CAST(20070807000000 AS VARCHAR),1,8) AS DATETIME ), 103)
```

Result:  07/08/2007

---

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST( SUBSTRING(CAST(20070807000000 AS VARCHAR),1,8) AS DATETIME ), 111)
```

Result: 2007/08/07

---

For more information about Date formats: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx